# Android Studio gradle project refresh failed in Xubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, android-studio

i just installed Xubuntu x32 bit. Then i installed android studio and java sdk. But when i open android studio project it shows me:

"Error:Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

This is the terminal output:

```
nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

This is JAVA_HOME path:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101" 
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose File->Project Structure  Write your /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_101 to "JDK location".
It`s help to me with the same problem.
But you must have write permissions to /usr/local/android-studio.

I have installed studio in my home folder.